# minikube service asks for authorization

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, wsl-2

I'm running minikube on wsl and was able to launch a mongoexpress-service from it. Since I'm running on wsl it starts a tunnel for the service.
However when I try to access the service from the provided url I get asked for username and password, Whose credentials do I provide
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? Did it help you solve problems? If yes, Please consider accepting and upvoting it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi Syed llhan, I am eager to hear back from you whether the suggested resolution helped you in overcoming the issue. If not, I am happy to assist you further.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the logs of the pod that runs `mongo-express` using:

```
kubectl logs <pod_name>
```

In the logs you'll find the basic authentication credentials, in the format of `username:password`.

Answer (score 0):

When running minikube with Mongoexpress-service, the authentication credentials required to access the service depend on the specific configuration and set-up of your minikube cluster and Mongoexpress deployment.

You can try checking the Mongoexpress deployment configuration and look for any configuration files such as YAML or JSON files that were used to create the deployment. Check if there are any environment variables or specific settings related to authentication, such as **MONGO_EXPRESS_USERNAME** and  **MONGO_EXPRESS_PASSWORD** as per this official [MongoDB documentation.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/authenticate-a-user/#std-label-authentication-auth-as-user) You can also refer to the [blog](https://anuradha.hashnode.dev/kubernetes-with-mongo-express-app) authored  by Anuradha Aggarwal for additional information.